# How do I make a SwiftUi Button's text larger and/or bold

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Say I have a Button in SwiftUI:

```
Button("Tap me") {
    print("Button tapped!")
}
```

How can I can I make the font size of the Button's text larger and bold?

Comment: Best thing I found so far is to apply: 

`Button("Tap me") { print("Button tapped!") } .font(.system(size: 30))`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`bold()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/bold()) `Text` modifier on a `Button`'s label.

Example:

```
Button {
    print("Button tapped!")
} label: {
    Text("Tap me").bold()
}
```

To make the text larger *and* bold, just chain the modifiers:

```
Button {
    print("Button tapped!")
} label: {
    Text("Tap me")
        .font(.title)
        .bold()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You are right about using `.system(size: )`
on macOS you need to create a `PlainButtonStyle` button in order for the text to stay inside the button. This is how I have done it

```swift
Button("Tap me") {
  print("Button Tapped!")
}.padding()
 .font(.system(size: 20, weight: Font.Weight.bold))
 .foregroundColor(Color.white)
 .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.blue))
 .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Answer (score 7):

```swift
Button("Tap me") {
    print("Button tapped!")
}.font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .default))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a toolbar and want the confirmation/add/save button to be bold, as it's standard in iOS, you just have tell the the toolbar that your button is a confirmation item.

```swift
List {
  // ...
}
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
    Button("Add") {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

You simply wrap your button in a `ToolbarItem` with the `placement: .confirmationAction`.

That way, the button will be placed on the top right in your toolbar and appears **bold** as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase font size with `.font(.system(size: <font size>))` method. As for the bold part, you can put text between two pairs of `*`. This allows you to make bold specific parts of text or the whole thing.

```swift
Button(action: {}, 
       label: { 
           Text("Tap **me**").font(.system(size: <font size>))
})
```